Error in pval[parms, , drop = TRUE] : subscript out of bounds with Publish function in R with large model?
I am using the Publish function to generate a regression table for a logistic model.
The code works for a single variable.
publish(BTRE2WithNA.TxAfterBMResectionNoPostOpMRI.logit)
                      Variable Units OddsRatio        CI.95  p-value 
 TxAfterBMResectionNoPostOpMRI    No       Ref                       
                                 Yes      1.40 [0.08;25.14]   0.8194 
                                  NA      0.55  [0.23;1.29]   0.1665 

However, when I try to apply the same function to a larger model, I get an error.
publish(step.model)
Error in pval[parms, , drop = TRUE] : subscript out of bounds


I can create the table manually.
> step.model.or<-exp(cbind(OR=coef(step.model), confint(step.model)))
Waiting for profiling to be done...
There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
> step.model.or
                                                         OR        2.5 %       97.5 %
(Intercept)                                    1.720787e-02  0.001511094 1.538311e-01
Demo.Age                                       9.787243e-01  0.955234510 1.001999e+00
Demo.GenderFemale                              2.097839e+00  0.752934085 6.043500e+00
Primary.Tumor.TypeBreast Cancer                6.114878e-01  0.206326184 1.795357e+00
Primary.Tumor.TypeColorectal Cancer            2.172218e-06           NA 3.345559e+58
Primary.Tumor.TypeLung Cancer - Non Small Cell 2.076465e-01  0.060295104 6.590015e-01
Primary.Tumor.TypeLung Cancer - Small Cell     4.436458e-01  0.044501960 3.385925e+00
Primary.Tumor.TypeLung Cancer - Unspecified    3.412866e+00  0.617944006 1.928514e+01
Primary.Tumor.TypeRenal Cell Cancer            1.993938e+00  0.285494591 1.562677e+01
BM.Parynchma.Loc.SupratentorialYes             3.387667e+00  0.929985787 1.500640e+01
BM.Parynchma.Loc.SupratentorialNA              3.129057e+01  6.554945246 1.935268e+02
BM.Supratentorial.Lesion.CorticalYes           3.098599e+01 12.032608544 9.545573e+01
BM.Supratentorial.Lesion.CorticalNA                      NA           NA           NA
TxAfterBMRadiotherapyYes                       2.580500e+00  1.122821061 6.201931e+00
TxAfterBMRadiotherapyNA                        2.535902e+00  0.747075851 8.813694e+00
TxAfterBMChemotherapoyYes                      2.053529e+00  0.927058572 4.660850e+00
TxAfterBMChemotherapoyNA                                 NA           NA           NA

Is there a way to fix the Publish code issue?
